# In the Microsoft LUIS platform, is there a limit to the number of apps I can create?

Tags: azure, artificial-intelligence, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I notice there is a limit on the number of intents per application on LUIS.ai, but is there also a limit on the number of applications one can create?

Reason I ask is I am developing a platform that will require many more than 500 possible intents, since I am limited to 500 per application.  A way around it is to split intents up into different apps, but is there a limit on apps?

Thanks

Comment: I did not find the information in the documentation, would also be interested to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not documented at this time, but according to the LUIS team there is no limit to the number of LUIS apps you can make.

Comment: That is our information as well. We have had several hundred in the past